# Azure (C) drive testing

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine

Is azure default (c) drive is SSD ?
Today i test it using AS SSD BENCHMARK. According to the test report i don't think so that c drive is SSD
[image: Azure C Drive Test Result]

Answer (score 0):

In azure the DS, DS_v2 and GS series have a default a SSD drive when you select a Premium Storage account.

Here you can read all about [premium storage on msdn](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-premium-storage/).

Comment: i m using ds11 with premium disk support but disk speed make me disappointed.